# How to monitor how many people are using the GeoServer simultaneously?

Tags: geoserver

I would like to know if there is any way to monitor how many simultaneous accesses to the GeoServer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [monitoring extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/index.html)